# How to use ojdbc with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jdbc

I'm new to Gradle so I have awfully big problems and one of them is about the Oracle JDBC driver. I just want to get connection to DB and I already used a JDBC driver in my previous project, but that did not use Gradle. Now, I see that I have to show dependency on driver, but this just didn't work. I already used all of the advice I found:

- I tried to add connector.jar to VM options,
- to create dependency with `implementation("com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:21.1.0.0")`, but it simply doesn't work.
- After I use `compile 'com.oracle:ojdbc8:21.1.0.0'`, I got `Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.oracle:ojdbc8:21.1.0.0]` and that's just killing me.
- I also tried to use local Maven repository and I have downloaded .jar, but it doesn't work either.
- I also just tried to add this lib dependency in IntelliJ, using *File->Project Structure->+* and creating ojdbc8 class with path to this file directly.

Full version of my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in 
    Java.id 'application'
}
repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
    implementation("com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:21.1.0.0")
    compile 'com.oracle:ojdbc8:21.1.0.0'
    // Use JUnit test framework.
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.199'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.2.Final'
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'

}
application {
    mainClass = 'model.App'
}
```

I'd like to use this JDBC driver in one class, but I just can't. Can you help me, please?

Comment: _"it simply doesn't work."_ it doesn't work how? What error do you get? You should remove `compile 'com.oracle:ojdbc8:21.1.0.0'` entirely, those are the wrong coordinate, and `compile` is no longer available in recent Gradle versions as it has been replaced by `implementation`, which explains why you get a _"Could not find method compile()"_.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, even if i remove compile, i still get this: ```Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] ```
So, it raises in next test i have:
```@Test
public void shouldConnectToDB(){
        SessionFactory sessions = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessions.openSession();
    }```

Comment: Why are you trying to load the MySQL Connector/J class `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` when you have added the Oracle JDBC Driver? Which database system are you using, Oracle or MySQL? (The fact that the company Oracle also owns MySQL, doesn't mean that you can use the Oracle JDBC driver (which is for the Oracle DBMS) to connect to MySQL). If you're using MySQL, then add MySQL Connector/J (`implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.27'`), or if you're using Oracle, specify the Oracle JDBC driver class (`oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`).

Comment: @MarkRottevee, my endless gratitude. it worked!